# Tensorflow 2: get tensors values during the training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I want to get the value of the tensors during the training to calculate the mutual information between the representations; input, and output.

The `get_mutual_information(get_tensors())` in the code below should get the values of the tensors to perform the calculation.

I wrote the other function `get_tensors()` to get the values using `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name()` but this methods retruns always empty lists.

Do you know to get the values of the tensors after each epoch?  thanks, Mahmoud

Here is the code:

```
def get_tensors():
    tensors = []
    names = []
#     for tensor in tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node: 
#         names.append(tensor.name)
    for op in tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations():
        names.append(op.name)
    names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
    for name in names:
        tensors.append(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("%s:0" % name))
    return tensors
```

```
class Callback_1(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.mi_xt_all = []
        self.mi_ty_all = []
        self.epochs = []
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        print(get_tensors())
        mi_xt, mi_ty = get_mutual_information(get_tensors())
        self.mi_xt_all.append(mi_xt)
        self.mi_ty_all.append(mi_ty)
        self.epochs.append(epoch)
class Callback_2(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if(logs.get('acc')>0.98):
            self.model.stop_training = True
            print("\nReached 99.8% accuracy so cancelling training!")
callbacks_list = [Callback_1(), Callback_2()]

def train_with_mi():
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```